# nvtop shows x and q instead of lines (Google Cloud)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, encoding

I'm connected to a Google Cloud VM (Debian GNU/Linux 10 buster) via their web-based ssh emulator.

I have installed nvtop with `sudo apt-get install nvtop` without any issues.

However, all horizontal and vertical lines are shown as the letters x, q, l, k, etc. which is slightly annoying. It seems this is some kind of encoding issue.

How can I solve this while continuing to use the web-based ssh interface?

[image: nvtop output]

Comment: I am not sure what the browser UI is using for SSH. Tips: Ensure that the Debian ncurses library is the wide-character version (libncursesw5-dev).

Comment: Details which you have provided were not sufficient; please elaborate. You want to use the GCP WEB SSH CMD tool; you need to [troubleshoot](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop/releases). 
A. Update all the packages. 
B. Reboot VM.
C. Downgrade the Nvtop version. 
If everything fails, set up a terminal tool like PuTTY as it is available for all major OS's. Please refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/create-vm-with-gpus).